# Comparing Euclidean norm of two normal vectors

Tags: probability-distributions, euclidean-geometry, gaussian, large-deviations

Let $X_i$ ($i = 1,2$) be two random vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, with normal distribution with scalar covariance matrix $\sigma_i^2$ and center $\mu_i$ (in my case, $n = 2$). Is there a way to estimate the probability that $\Vert X_1 \geq \Vert X_2\Vert$ assuming, for instance, that $\Vert\mu_1\Vert \gg \Vert \mu_2 \Vert$ ? (this is the Euclidean norm).

What I tried so far:

- directly integrating the joint distribution of $(X_1, X_2)$ on the cone: this does not seem possible.
- writing the probability distribution for $\Vert X_1 \Vert^2$: this leads me to integrals of the form $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{\alpha \sin(\theta) + \beta \sin^2(\theta)} \sin^n(\theta) d\theta$, which I cannot make anything of.

Comment: What is a circular variance?

Comment: This means that the covariance matrix is scalar. (Since $n=2$ in my case, I meant that the variables are circularly symmetric). I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: What does "$\|\mu_1\|\gg \|\mu_2\|$" mean? That $\sigma_1+\sigma_2+\|\mu_1\|=o(\|\mu_2\|)$? -- You need to relate $\|\mu_2\|$, not only to $\|\mu_1\|$, but also to $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ in order to get a specific answer.

Comment: Do you want to upper or lower bound the probability?

Comment: @IosifPinelis You are obviously right; I left this “open” on purpose because I would be interested even in a result that needs a small tweak on the exact domination hypothesis. In my case I certainly have at least $\Vert \mu_2\Vert + \sigma_1 = o(\Vert \mu_1 \Vert)$, while $\sigma_2$ might be somewhat larger (though still $O(\mu_1)$).

Comment: Your question is still too "open". It needs to be more specific.